# variable scope issue in Javascript and angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can i solve the issue of scope of variable in the below case.

```js
Myapp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  var formvalues = {};
  
  $scope.somebuttonclick = function(){
    mycont.somefunctionB();
  };
  
  var mycont = {
      init: function(){
        formvalues.init = "some value init";
        this.somefunctionA();
      },
      somefunctionA: function(){
          formvalues.a= "some value a";
        alert(formvalues.init); //comes undefined when called from mycont.init
      },
      somefuntionB: function(){
          formvalues.b = "some valuee b";
           alert(formvalues.init); // comes "some value init" when called from buttonclick
      }
  };

}]);
```

Calling through button click, variable are defined correctly but when called from inside of mycont method, it say undefined. How to solve this

Comment: similar to this.someFunctionA()  ...I think you need to reference your inner functions by calling this. Otherwise you need to apply, bind, or call outside.

Comment: @Vontei How to apply bind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what exactly you are looking for but check this:

```
Myapp.controller('MyController', ['$scope','$log', function ($scope, $log) {

    var formvalues = {};/*this is empty at first*/

    var mycont = {
        init: function(){
            formvalues.init = "some value init";
        },
        somefunctionA: function(){
            formvalues.a= "some value a";
            /*mycont.init();*/ /*you can call it here, if not in somebuttonclick*/
            $log.log(formvalues.init);
            $log.log(formvalues.a);
        },
        somefunctionB: function(){
            formvalues.b = "some valuee b";
            /* mycont.init(); */ /*you can call it here, if not in somebuttonclick*/
            $log.log(formvalues.init);
            $log.log(formvalues.b);
        }
    };

    $scope.somebuttonclick = function(){
        mycont.init();/*you need to first call this function before you can use the value*/
        mycont.somefunctionA();
        mycont.somefunctionB();
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to bind `this` to the functions, or just access the functions as object properties like this:

```
mycont.someFunctionA()
```